# Images not loading anymore when re-rendering Meteor template

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I slightly extended the [discovermeteor tutorial](https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope/tree/488da0d469182beea700ae384d2e4177e17cbf0e) and added an image to every post in *post_item.html*:

```
<img src="discover.png" height="40px" />
```

After putting *discover.png* in the *public* folder everything seems to work as expected. However if you open the detail page (click on 'discuss') and come back to the overview (click on 'microscope' in the header) the pictures or not loading anymore. It happens in **Safari and Firefox**, in Chrome it's still working as expected. I put the example on http://img-notloading-safari.meteor.com

I don't know if this has something to do with it, but I noticed, the 'waitOn' function of iron:router is called twice when the overview is loaded in the beginning, but only once when I come back form the detail view and the pictures are not loading.

Any hint would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked at network requests in Firefox and for some reason it tries to load `http://img-notloading-safari.meteor.com/posts/discover.png`, which is not there. Maybe this happens because the template is rendered before the url changes.

I suggest you changing the url of the image in `<img src=` from `discover.png`, which is a relative url, to a `/discover.png`, that is, to absolute path.

Comment: What a stupid mistake. I was suspecting the router and anything else but the path to the image. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: use a '/' even if it is contained within a directory structure. So use '/f1/f2/f3/img.png' not 'f1/f2/f3/img.png'

Comment: Ah. @timebandit - Your comment just saved my day! Cheers.